# getting router error while exporting in express m

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

i am new, getting router error while exporting in express ,how to fix this and also in mongo model

Expecting successful exporting in both router as well as mongo model

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to export it like, in every router

```
module.exports =router
```

and for any MongoDB model, you created, use the same-->

```
module.exports=User (or any that you created)
```